# Layout inspector in Android Studio is disabled

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm confused.

[image]

How can I enable this? I can find no options. I've tried to run/debug/attach/pause
BTW, using menu Tools -> Android -> Layout Inspector I can launch it.

Comment: is your device connected? please check

Comment: i can debug my icon. this icon is disabled.